# How should I reconnect two switches to these six wires?

Tags: switch, installation, light

I did not take a photo prior removing old light switches. So, now I am basically stuck. Our home is from ‘53 and wanted to upgrade the original light switches.

From what I remember is that the left 4 wires were attached to one light switch to feed the outdoor light at the front door. The remaining two wires would feed an outlet below. This switch was connected with one black wire to the other switch.

I currently have and had to use two-way light switches only. How would I need to reconnect all? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Where does power come into this box at?  Also, was the outlet in question switched or always-hot?:

Comment: All wires have screw loops. How is it that six wires connected to two switches (which presumably had two screws each)?